# Uso de iframe con el siguiente error: "La página ha sido rechazada"

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Necesito mostrar ese mapa interactivo dentro de una página

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.submarinecablemap.com/#/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Estas notificando que es lo que estás haciendo. No estás preguntando nada ni mostrando tu proyecto en la cual haya el error. Edita tu pregunta y muestra tu proyecto en las partes que crees que aya el problema, junto con sus respectivas páginas

Comment: Observa que con otras urls si que funciona. Evidentemente esa url que pones en la pregunta está configurada para no ser mostrada en un iframe (protegida contra clonación)